# Why are my multi-dimensional array initializations not working?

Tags: java, arrays

For some reason, in IntelliJ (if that matters), when I try to initialize my 2D arrays, only the first box gets initialized for the size that I am specifying. i.e.
`int[][] grid = new int[9][9];`
and when I run through with the debugger, it shows that I've created an array that is `int[9][]`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? could it be that I need to update something? anything helps. Thank you.

Comment: The debugger is showing that `grid` is an `int[9][]`, i.e. an array of length 9 of `int` arrays. Each of the 9 subarrays can have different lengths, so the debugger cannot show anything for the second `[]`.

Comment: Java doesn't really have 2D arrays. What you have is an array that contains arrays. You'll have to initialize each of the arrays in your array separately, for example in a `for` loop.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is having the wrong expectation for how arrays work. You cannot make an array that contains 9 `int[9]`s, because `int[9]` is not a *type*, `int[]` is.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a debugger representation.

It always works fine.
It **do** create a two dimensional array in memory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] grid = new int[9][9];

    System.out.println(grid.length);
    System.out.println(grid[0].length);
}
```

This code will always return dimensions properly as:

```
9
9
```

What you might get in a debugger is something like this - where definitely is not written **int[9][9]** what you are expected, however this is a representation only - there is nothing with correctness.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem and I've found @Misho Zhghenti's answer is the best! Yes, IntelliJ's representation in debug leads to confusion. A multidimensional array in Java isn't really like that, is just an array of arrays.

Thank you @EthanB21 @Misho Zhghenti

Answer (score -1):

Please post complete code, what exactly you have written and debugging.

Restart your IDE and check once with below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] grid = new int[9][9];
    int value = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = ++value;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            System.out.print(((j == 0) ? "" : ", ") + grid[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Note**: IDE may misbehave too or might be responding late.